# Use of pdflatex with powerdot

Tags: powerdot

I know that a document with `pstricks` code can be compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape` using `auto-pst-pdf` so that one may enjoy the power of `pstricks` while using `microtype` at the same time.

Can a `powerdot` presentation (which uses `pstricks`) be compiled in the same way, or must one resort to using `latex`+`dvips`+`ps2pdf` in this case?

Comment: I am using powerdot and compilation process ( in TexMaker: Latex + dvips + viewPS) takes so long (about 75s) It is very annoying when you have to wait 75s each time you want to see your changes in the text.... DVI is unreadable :) and Latex + dvips + ps2pdf + view PDF takes even 15s longer :) Is there any option to shorten this time? I tried Led... Still compilation time to PDF is unacceptable. Any thoughts?

Comment: @AdiSilesian [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question won't be seen by many people here, so it would be best to repost it as a fresh question. [Follow-up questions](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-post-a-follow-up-question-why-and-how) like this are more than welcome! Please use the "Ask Question" link for your new question; there you can link to this question to provide the background.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible to run `powerdot` with `pdflatex` and sometimes[*] *not* with `xelatex`, as it is *completely* based on PSTricks. However, using `microtype` in a presentations is no real advantage, too less text  ...

And using PSTricks together with the presentation class `beamer` and `xelatex` is possible.

**[*] As at 2019 powerdot presentation files can still, most often, be compiled direct to PDF using XeLaTeX**, however the page layout may need minor adjustments first.